# Turn off currency formatting on iPhone for HTML input

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, validation

This is input (numeric keyboard should be used)

```
<input type="number" id="Amount" maxlength="8" autocorrect="off"/>
```

this is JS attached to the input

```
$("#Amount").change(function() { this.value = formatNumber(this.value); });
```

where formatNumber formats value in pattern ###.###.### i.e. dot is used as a thousand separator, no decimals. Described behavior works on Android and desktop browsers, but fails on iPhone in this way:

- 123123 is turned into 123,123
- 123000 is turned into 123

How to turn off this behavior programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I found so far

```
<input type="type" id="Amount" maxlength="8" autocorrect="off" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

So, type="text" with pattern="[0-9]*" will trigger numeric keyboard without automatic currency formatting. Works fine on Apple devices (iPad, iPhone), but doesn't trigger numeric keyboard on Android devices. That's way this JS is needed:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
   $("input[pattern='[0-9]*']").prop("type", "number");  
}
```